# How to use Ktor socket in android?

Tags: android, ktor

Ktor has a sample chat app: https://ktor.io/samples/app/chat.html

and I want to use in my android app, I don't have any idea how. If anyone knows could you share please how?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android, but I'm pretty sure you could follow the same idea. Have you run into any specific issues?

Comment: @HadiHariri yes it was not working, It was throwing an exception related to Coroutines, I don't remember which one. It would good if JetBrains team provide us some samples related to sockets on android and multiplatform. Thanks in advance, I was really surprised that the Author of KTOR responded to my question.